# Zooming gradually stops

Tags: 3d-view

At one time, it seems that I made a mistake in something, and the object I was creating went far.

[image]

Then, even I scroll the mouse wheel to zoom it, it gradually stops zooming, and eventually stops.

Someone can help?

Thank you.

Comment: Please always try searching for existing questions which may apply to your problem.